# paypal user login page (page after clicking the paypal button) reloads indefinitely, after adding "&vault=true&intent=subscription"

Tags: django, rest, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPal for subscription related service, I have earlier implemented for single time payment by adding the Paypal button via adding the script

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID"></script>
```

but for subscription as per the documentation

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#subscriptions-with-smart-payment-buttons
we are supposed to add

```
&vault=true&intent=subscription
```

also thus making it

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client id=SB_CLIENT_ID&vault=true&intent=subscription"></script>
```

but after adding this I get the following error in the chrome console and the login page reloads indefinitely

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
> (Bad Request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your second snippet, `client id` in place of the correct parameter name.

This sandbox URL works fine:

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&vault=true&intent=subscription
```

Comment: thanks it got fixed, guess there was space between them that's why. but now I get "Uncaught Error: Must pass createSubscription with intent=subscription" error what could that be ?

Comment: As stated, you need a `createSubscription` function if you intend to integrate Subscriptions.  You can find information in the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#create-the-subscription